# Is it possible to create a custom Windows 10 Settings pane?

Tags: windows-10

I know it's possible to create and register an executable or .dll as an additional Windows Control Panel via the registry but would like to integrate with the Windows 10 Settings application, for instance as an additional entry in the 'Network and Internet' Settings pane.  I've found a [reference to OEM Partner Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn707973(v=vs.85).aspx) but am neither an OEM, nor a Partner, and just want to add Control-Panel like functionality in an obvious place.  I can't find any more developer documentation on SO or MSDN that relates to this so wonder if it's possible or whether MS have locked the Settings application a little tighter than the old (and maybe to be deprecated?) Control Panel?  What's best practice for Windows 10 system-wide settings applications/applets/panels?